# How can I stop playing a movie?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I stop playing a movie? 
I want to stop a playing a movie, when I use `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a movie.

Comment: Press the **Stop** button. It usually looks like a square. (If that's not what you're looking for, please edit your question to include more details.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [movieController stop], should do the trick. It's defined in the MPMediaPlayback Protocol.